# What Electronic Flight Display is this?

Tags: avionics

I just watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbqDTuAQoi4) in which the avionics surprised me. It looks like a half Garmin G600, attached on his yoke.

[image: Screenshot from the video]

- What is that and is it permanently attached to the yoke or is it portable?
- Could it be for aircraft that can not be retrofitted? Because there is also something to see what looks like a ADS-B-receiver to me:

[image: Screenshot of possible ADS-B rec]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The top unit is a Garmin 696 portable aviation GPS unit on a yoke mount.  The lower is a Stratus ADS-B receiver.

Answer (score 5):

At first this reminded me of the Garmin G3X. However, it is mounted on the yoke and must be a GPSMAP 695 or 696

https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/p/14860